# Equation: placing subscript explanation at the very end

Tags: equations

Most of the times I use equations that have subscripts and sometimes I want to give a short explanation of the subscripts, e.g., what are the limits, or which are the categories, should they be small enough.

In this minimal example I do not like the placement of the subscript explanation (I have used `\qquad`) but it is still quite close to the main part. I would like it to be at the very end of the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\author{PSK}

\begin{document}
Some stuff ...

\begin{equation}
V_i = a_i + B_i \qquad (i = 1, \dots, N)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\qquad` is the standard amount of space to use here.

Comment: @AndrewSwann can I make the subscript explanation right justified? I mean only this part, not the whole equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I introduce `\notateeqn{equation}{notation}` to do the trick.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\newcommand\notateeqn[2]{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\displaystyle#1}{\makebox[\textwidth]{\hfill#2}}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
Some stuff ...
\begin{equation}
\notateeqn{V_i = a_i + B_i}{(i = 1, \dots, N)}
\end{equation}
\noindent\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ADDENDUM

Trying to satisfy both egreg's strong recommendation, as well as trying to satisfy the OP's added request for a fixed equation indent, I show how my technique can be used to fix the indent of the equation by defining a new length `\eqnindent`, while still leaving room for a right-aligned notation.  In this MWE, I use the notation space for things other than the `(i =...)` specifier (so as not to offend egreg's sensibilities).  I set an artificial "ruler" just so one can confirm that the indent levels of .3, .2, and .5 of `\textwidth` are properly met.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, makeidx, graphicx, stackengine}
\newlength\eqnindent
\stackMath
\newcommand\notateeqn[2]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \hspace{\dimexpr2\eqnindent-\textwidth+\wd0\relax}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\displaystyle#1}{\makebox[\textwidth-\eqnindent]{\hfill#2}}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\setlength\eqnindent{.3\textwidth}
Setting indent to 0.3 textwidth
\begin{equation}
\notateeqn{V_i = a_i + B_i,\qquad(i = 1, \dots, N)}{(Notation)}
\end{equation}

Setting indent to 0.2 textwidth
\setlength\eqnindent{.2\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\notateeqn{V_i = a_i + B_i}{(The Equation Name)}
\end{equation}

Setting indent to 0.5 textwidth
\setlength\eqnindent{.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
\notateeqn{V_i = a_i + B_i}{(My Notation)}
\end{equation}
\noindent$|$\hrulefill$\cdot$\hrulefill$|$\hrulefill$\cdot$\hrulefill$|$\hrulefill$\cdot$%
\noindent\hrulefill$|$\hrulefill$\cdot$\hrulefill$|$\hrulefill$\cdot$\hrulefill$|$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is a sublime solution. Another favour if possible. Can we have predetermined distance from the number, let us say 1.5cm, and the main equation?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis You may like it, but it's not the way to go; a `\qquad` is just what you need. Really.

Comment: @egreg Is there a specific reason for that? Is there a rule dictating that we should always used `\qquad`, and if so, why?

Comment: @PantelisKazakis The specification `(i=1,2,\dots,n)` belongs to the equation, it's not something separated from it.

Comment: @PantelisKazakis I have added an addendum to my answer.  Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes what a superb LaTeX technician! Yes, this is what I am looking for! P.S. I fear that egreg does not approve though :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the `\flalign` environment and `mathtools` (which loads `amsmath`): it has many enhancements to amsmath, corrects a couple of bugs, and of special interest in your case, defines a math version of `\llap`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\author{PSK}

\begin{document}
Some stuff ...

\begin{flalign}
 &  & V_i  &   = a_i + B_i   &  & \mathllap{(i = 1, \dots, N)}
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, there's a chance that for a long equation, the explanation overlaps the end of the equation. In such a case, you can put the explanation on next line (unnumbered with `\notag`), but still at the end of the line.

Comment: +1 But the `\mathllap` is not necessary here and perhaps even not helpful, it allows the right text to overlap the equation in the middle.

Comment: I was wondering if we can make it more neat. That is, the equation number to be let us say 1.5cm from the actual equation, this means that someone would not need the `&` all the time. And of course again the explanation should be at the very end.

Comment: @Andrew Swann:the `\mathllap`, as I see it, is here for the centring of the main (middle group) equation: LaTeX places it as if there were no explanation. Of course the explanation must not be too long, or else it should be placed on next line. Anyway  you can play with which part of the "explanation" is "llapped" so to say. For instance : `\mathllap{1 \leq i,j \leq} m+1-k`. Or, if it's a text explanation, use a smaller fontsize.